# how to run java program from flash drive that has classes in package, from command line?

Tags: java

I have an assignment where I have to submit my code in flash drive.

I did all coding in eclipse and getting all output. I tried running it through command line and it works. I copied all java files and class files to flash drive and tried again through command line it works in my laptop. but when I take that dive and put it my desktop computer and run through command line, it can not recognise the classes that are in the package.

I have a package a1.cis568 under this package I have several classes. main class is `A1` and other classes are `Circle`, `Point`, `PlaneCircle`, `EHashtable`, `CHashtable` in the same package.

I have to use following line on command line to compile and run my program through flash drive, (don't have to change any classpath while doing so)

```
E:>        
E:>javac -d . A1.java        
E:>java a1.cis568.A1
```

When I was searching for solution I found that I can install JDK on flash drive and run the code. I tried installing JDK but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: what errors to you get when you try to run it?

Comment: When I run main class(A1.java) it does not recognize other classes object that I am creating in A1.java it says " A1.java:120: error: cannot find symbol PlaneCircle pcr5 = new PlaneCircl(po5, 9999f)" this is same for object of other classes that I am using in A1.java. Gives me 42 errors in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have troubles compiling your source code!

Since you navigate trought the package hierarchy to where `A1.java` is located and then try to compile, the compiler cannot find other classes which `A1` depends on and which are not in the same directory. You have to tell it where to find them, this done using `javac`'s option `-sourcepath`.

So from the same location of the class `A1.java` you could compile your code using something like this:

```
E:> javac -d . A1.java -sourcepath ..\..\
```

Here `..\..\` is used to tell that the sources can be found two directories above the actual directroy (based on your package tree `a1\cis568\`).

But to make things easy I would suggest you compile from the root of you source code tree. In this case the `sourcepath` and `classpath` are the actual working directory per default.

So navigate in the commad prompt to the location where the package/directory `a1` is, then compile like this:

```
E:> javac -d . a1\cis568\A1.java
```

The comipiler should be able to find all classes on which `A1` depends on (assuming they all exist with the correct package inside the root of your source code).

Run with

```
E:> java a1.cis568.A1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse you can easily export the project as a runnable jar. Copy the jar file and source to your flash drive. Execute from command line via the following

java -jar [runnable jar filename]

Comment: I actually lost hope for this question but thanks for replying. I tried this. but when I use jar file, I have to use A1.jar to execute in command line. And my submission does not use it. it uses "javac -d . A1.java". And I am so confused, that how this works with a flash drive.

Comment: But `A1.java`is not supposed to live in the top level directory. It must be in `a1/cis568/A1.java`. Either you put the A1 class in an unamed package or you use `javac a1/cis568/A1.java`